# DbContext class not founded

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm trying to experiment with entity framework. I have added a reference to `System.Data.Entity` but `Visual Studio 2010` tells me that `DbContext` class is not found.

```
using System.Data.Entity;
namespace WingtipToys.Models
{
    public class ProductContext : DbContext
    {
        public ProductContext()
            : base("WingtipToys")
        {
        }
        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }
}
```

How do i fix this?

Comment: Do you have entity framework installed ?

Comment: use library package manager to properly install EF for your project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Library Package Manager to properly install EF for your project.

Package Manager Console option is also an easy one to follow

http://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/

Comment: I ran the nuget console as follow PM> Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 6.1.3
Installing 'EntityFramework 6.1.3'.
Successfully installed 'EntityFramework 6.1.3'.
Desktop.Client already has a reference to 'EntityFramework 6.1.3'.
But the compiler gave the same errors, regarding DbContext and DbSet. What is going?